# sort rows by split of dot-separated-string values

Tags: postgresql

I have an index column, string type, where the data is in format like "1.5.4.10.7".

I need to make a query returns the values sorted as if the column were an array of integers derived by splitting the string on the '.' character.

I can extract the array with:

```
select string_to_array(index,'.') as index_array from performance_indicators;
```

How can I 1) convert the array elements to integers, and 2) sort on the array of integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cast the string array to integer array and sort by the value, e.g.:

```
with a_table(col) as (
    values ('1.2.3.4'), ('10.2.3.4'), ('3.4.5.6')
)

select string_to_array(col, '.')::int[]
from a_table
order by 1;

 string_to_array 
-----------------
 {1,2,3,4}
 {3,4,5,6}
 {10,2,3,4}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: perfect... concise and elegant. thank you very much, @klin